# Correct way to use multiple inheritance with Qt (pysyde6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside, multiple-inheritance, pyside6

I'm trying to use multiple inheritance with my and Qt-derived classes. But faced with the fact that the `__init__()` method from my class is not called when I use `super()` to call `__init__()` for base classes. I suppose that's because Qt classes do not use `super()` in their constructors.

The example that does not work properly ("BASE INIT" was never printed):

```py
class OptionBase(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("BASE INIT", self)
        super().__init__(*args, *kwargs)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
class OptionLineEdit(QLineEdit, OptionBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've tried several variants (change ordering of base classes, use metaclass, etc.). But only got either coredump or some strange python errors like: `"RuntimeError: '__init__' method of object's base class (OptionLineEdit) not called"` for the line where the statement `print()` is located.

The only way I managed to make it to work is the following:

```py
class OptionBase(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("BASE INIT", self)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
class OptionLineEdit(QLineEdit, OptionBase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        OptionBase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

So, I don't call any further `__init__` in my base class (to avoid "double initialization" error). And I have to call all `__init__` manually in the child class.

It this correct way in such situation or am I missing something?

P.S. The MRO looks correct for me:

```
<class 'ui.widgets.option_lineedit.OptionLineEdit'>
<class 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QLineEdit'>
<class 'ui.widgets.option_base.OptionBase'>
<class 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget'>
<class 'PySide6.QtCore.QObject'>
<class 'PySide6.QtGui.QPaintDevice'>
<class 'Shiboken.Object'>
<class 'object'>
```

Comment: "It this correct way in such situation" yes, pretty much, assuming the QT library doesn't support cooperative multiple inheritance, then you cannot use `super` the way you would like to. I guess you could try to write an adaptor class, but I don't think taht would work beause you'd have to adapt all the QT classes you seem to want to use

Comment: although: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/multiinheritance.html

Comment: Don't ever try to inherit from two Qt classes (unless you really, *really* know what you're doing). Very few Qt class support multiple-inheritance, so there's hardly ever any real need for it. Just use a simple mixin class instead: i.e. in your example, do `class OptionBase:` (i.e. with no base-class, so just inheriting from `object`) and `class OptionLineEdit( OptionBase, QLineEdit):`, and then make sure you use `super`. (NB: if `OptionBase` doesn't override any `QLineEdit` methods, the order of the base-classes isn't important).

Comment: @ekhumoro You are right. Your variant also works. The only drawback of removing `QWidget` from `OptionBase():` is that pylint reports a lot of errors for the lines where I call `QWidget` methods via `self`. Obviously, in this case pylint is not aware that `OptionBase` is never used standalone, and always is mixed with some Qt widget-based class.

Comment: @GrAnd So much for pylint ;-) There are other source code checkers available...

Comment: @GrAnd The "variant" suggested by ekhumoro not only works, but is also the only acceptable option. Using `super()` is also what should always be done in order to ensure that method resolution and argument usage are properly done. Remember that both PySide and PyQt are bindings that wrap C++ objects and functions, and that is also done by some "delicate magic" done under the hood when Qt objects are created and handled, something we normally are not aware of, and should not be messed with. While calling the inherited function with `self` works, it shouldn't be done like that, and that's also »

Comment: @GrAnd » important to consider as some overridden functions of Qt objects do *not* call the function of the inherited class, or do it in a different way, so you may call the base implementation when you shouldn't (because it was already called or because it *shouldn't* be called) or in the wrong way (with arguments that are not what the original subclass would use). If you have issues with the code checker, then solve *those* issues: as smart as a checker can be, it is not always aware of indirect or dynamic correlations, and you need to "explain" it to it, not try to "fix" *valid* code.